# Updating my version of php to the latest 5.5 version

Tags: yum, php, upgrade

I'm trying to update the version of php 5.5 to the latest version (5.5.20 at the time of writing).

I'm doing this on a CentOS v6 machine.

I've tried following the steps here:

https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/

But when I run

```
yum install php55w
```

I get a ton of errors like this:

```
file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/ctype.so from install of php55w-common-5.5.20-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.5.7-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

Is there any way I can get round this?

Comment: Any reason why you are not following the instructions on the page? It nowhere seems to provide that particular `yum` command (it does indicate `yum install php55w php55w-opcache`). Did you also skip the `rpm` prerequisite?

Comment: Have you tried removing your earlier php install from the remi repositories?

Comment: I don't need the opcache, @Anthon. I didn't skip the rpm step; I also ran `rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, ow do I remove the php install from the remi repositories?

Comment: @TolaOdejayi: you can inch your way forward by starting with `yum remove php-common`, then your `yum install php55w` will conflict for the next packe, and so on. (FWIW, remi [offers 5.5.20]([remi]()), so I don't know why you're not offered that as an update andhave to switch repositories.)